# Can't I integrate the magnetic field this way?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was looking up the derivation for the magnetic field of a circular current loop, to see if there was a generalized solution. I came across one that solved it for the z-axis, finding $B_z$. But it made me think, couldn't we just solve the integral for any point, knowing its coordinates $a, b$ and $z$ relative to some point of the loop that we would consider as our origin? That way, $r^2=a^2+b^2+z^2$. Therefore:

$$B= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{I(d \vec{l} \times \hat{r})}{(a^2+b^2+z^2)}=\frac{\mu_02\pi RI}{4\pi(a^2+b^2+z^2)}$$

Disregarding the practicality of this method, or the fact that this would only give us the modulus of the magnetic field, are there any mathematical or conceptual problems with this?

Comment: I believe the problem you run into here is that $\hat{r}$ is a function of a and b, so the integral can't be evaluated as you did above. You'll notice also that your answer is a scalar where it should be a vector - there's some stuff missing here.

Comment: @SeñorO Yes, but if you're integrating with respect to $dl$, and the path of the loop does not depend on a, b and z, shouldn't it not matter? I know it's should give you a vector, but I suppose you could solve that by either adding a "placeholder vector" or calculating the modulus directly.

Comment: Yes, you can integrate, but there doesn't seem to be a nice formula for the result when you leave the axis of symmetry. You can use a computer to get numeric results for individual points. Or you may find some surfaces along which there are "nice" formulae.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy So is $B=\frac{\mu_02\pi RI}{4\pi(a^2+b^2+z^2)}$ wrong? Or do you mean it's not nice?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I tried to solve for the general solution at one time, and was unable to find a formula for the integral. So, without checking very carefully, I suspect your answer is wrong. Are you integrating around the loop?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yeah, I'm integrating around the loop.

Comment: You need to explicitly work out $d\vec{l} \times \hat{r}$. It's a vector, not a scalar, and it depends on a, b and z.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your evaluation isn't correct is because $ \hat{r}$ is a little more complicated than meets the eye in this case. Remember it represents the unit vector from the wire to the observation point. It is **not** simply the unit vector from the origin to the wire nor the origin to the observation point (both situations would make the integral more doable).

The vector from the wire to the observation point $\vec{r'}$ goes as

$ \vec{r'} = \hat{x} (a - R\cos\theta') + \hat{y}(b - R\sin\theta') + \hat{z} (z)$

There is no shortcut for $\hat{r'}$, you must explicitly calculate $\frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}$.

Then you need to express $\vec{dl}$ as $\vec{dl} = [\hat{x}(R\cos\theta') + \hat{y}(R\sin\theta') ] d\theta'$ and then you can integrate from $\theta' = 0$ to $2\pi$.

The integral becomes solvable when you're on the z-axis because then a and b are 0 and also the trig functions integrate to 0 due to symmetry ($0$ to $2\pi$).

It also becomes easier if you move very far away from the loop - then you can assume that $\hat{r'} \approx \hat{r} $ and then there is no need to include $\hat{r}$ in the integral (and it behaves like a magnetic dipole).